# Moving Hyperlink from Excel to Word Document and pasting in specific range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro that takes information from an Excel sheet and opens and fills in a pre-existing Word Email Template. I wanted the information from each sheet to go into a specified section of this document and each row to fill in portions of a sentence. I was able to do this successfully by implementing a find and replace that loops for each row of the excel document.

However the hyperlinks only come through as text and from my understanding can't be stored as an object and then used to replace text, like the string content of cells. Subsequently, I've tried to use the Hyperlinks.Add function and my code successfully brings the hyperlinks form each row into the document, but I'm unable to control where in the document their placed. From my understanding this might be due to the expression before the Hyperlinks.Add and whats in the anchor.

The goal is to have the information come through in a row by row basis with the hyperlinks included. Ie.

Contents of Cell(A1) "Manual text" Hyperlink from Cell(B1)

Contents of Cell(A2) "Manual text" Hyperlink from Cell(B2)...etc

I'm new to VBA so apologies in advance for any redundancies or clunkiness, any tips would be a great help.

```
    Option Explicit
Sub CreateWordDocuments()
Dim CustRow1, CustCol1, LastRow1, TagName1, TagValue1 As String
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim WordApp        As Word.Application: Set WordApp = New 
Word.Application
Dim WordDoc        As Word.Document
Dim WordContent As Word.Range
Dim WordTempLoc As FileDialog


Set WordTempLoc = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With WordTempLoc
    .Title = "Select Word file to attach"
    .Filters.Add "Word Type Files", "*.docx,*.doc", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection
    DocLoc = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NoSelection:
 WordApp.Visible = True
 Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, 
ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
 Dim linkText As String
 Dim link As String


 LastRow1 = Worksheets("pipeline.gs.closed-or- 
cancelle").Range("F9999").End(xlUp).Row
  TagName1 = "PIPELINECLOSED" 'Tag Name

  For CustRow1 = 2 To LastRow1
        linkText = Worksheets("pipeline.gs.closed-or- 
cancelle").Cells(CustRow1, "J")
        link = Worksheets("pipeline.gs.closed-or- 
 cancelle").Cells(CustRow1, "O")
        TagValue1 = Worksheets("pipeline.gs.closed-or- 
cancelle").Cells(CustRow1, "G") & " Manual Text"
        With WordApp.Selection.Find
             .Execute FindText:=TagName1
```

Highlighted Code Below

```
             WordDoc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WordApp.Selection.Range, 
Address:=link, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
```

^^

```
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Post the code itself instead, in your question, so that people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: You need to execute the Find before the range will be selected: after that you can add the hyperlink.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750388/need-to-expand-multiple-find-and-replace-in-ms-word-from-a-list-in-ms-excel-to-r/60752057#60752057

Comment: @macropod thanks for linking this, I have come across it, but they use this .EndKey to assign where the hyperlink is added while i would prefer if possible to add the link at a particular piece of text in the word document

Comment: @TimWilliams i just edited to execute as per the Microsoft documentation but i'm not sure if the call is incorrect

Comment: `Anchor:=Selection.Range` should be `Anchor:=WordApp.Selection.Range`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you this is now pasting in the correct spot but I am getting a "Run-time error '4120 Bad Parameter" after the template is filled in. And the debugger highlights the "WordDoc.Hyperlinks.Add expression..."

Comment: Where is that coming from?  There's no way for me to suggest anything without more info.

Comment: @TimWilliams The macro will now run and paste the hyperlinks at the select spot in the word document, but after the template is filled, in a separate window from Microsoft Visual Basic appears with the above message. When I select the Debug option the code which I've commented in the original question is highlighted in the visual basic window containing the module.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to check the values being supplied to Hyperlinks.Add are correct.

Comment: «I have come across it, but they use this .EndKey to assign where the hyperlink is added» It most certainly *does not*!!! In fact, it uses Find to locate the text - which is precisely what you say you want to achieve.